# Why my "index.jsp" can't recognize my variable from Controller, using java and Spring

Tags: java, spring, jstl

My Controller code

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
    public String mainPage(ModelMap model, HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(request.getMethod().equals("GET")){
            model.addAttribute("test", "test");
            model.addAttribute("var", "Hello");
            return "index";
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

My AppCondig code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix(".jsp");
        return  internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer){
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

My index.jsp where i get " Cannot resolve variable 'var'

```
<head>
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
    <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hello World! </h2>
<td>${var}</td>
</body>
</html>
```

I use version 3 in my web.xml as follows

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
```

And I don't know why my variable isn't recognize in ".jsp" file because I follow all de information I read about this topic. I use the latest version of IntelliJ IDEA

Answer (score 1):

```
internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix(".jsp");
```

Should be :

```
internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
```

Comment: Oh! That was the problem! Thank you very much!